# tensorflow_probability: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_probability.* has no attribute '*'

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I'm trying to reproduce a snippet of code I found on google colaboratory ([here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Gaussian_Process_Regression_In_TFP.ipynb#scrollTo=jw-_1yC50xaM)) and I have problems with the methods used (tfb.Shift and tfp.util.TransformedVariable) that I can't find in the documentation.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfb = tfp.bijectors
tfd = tfp.distributions
tf.enable_v2_behavior()

constrain_positive = tfb.Shift(np.finfo(np.float64).tiny)(tfb.Exp())

amplitude_var = tfp.util.TransformedVariable(
    initial_value=1.,
    bijector=constrain_positive,
    name='amplitude',
    dtype=np.float64)
```

I get

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors' has no attribute 'Shift'
```

and

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_probability.python.util' has no attribute 'TransformedVariable'
```

Could be a version issue?

I'm using  tensorflow 2.0.0 and tensorflow-probability 0.8.0 and I see that in colab notebook is used `@tf.function` so I thought it used tensorflow 2.0.0 too.

What can I use instead?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

It seems there are lot of issues in `tensorflow_probability`'s dependency management, unfortunately. I tried your code and got a slightly different import error.

You can try the following workarounds:

1. Use the latest release of tensorflow: `pip install tensorflow==2.1.0rc2`
2. Use CoLab, where tensorflow and tensorflow_probably are already installed by default: https://colab.sandbox.google.com/

Comment: Thanks but both using colab and updating the version I always get the same error